# How to get lightswitch table data in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lightswitch-2013

I am new and beginner in light-Switch,

I am doing light-Switch with MVC.

**Let me explain my scenario:**

First I have created one light switch application. In this app having one project is called [ProjectName].Server

Then I've Connect my SQL database in Light-Switch application. And try CRUD operation via Light-Switch screen and its working fine.

In This server project I've create MVC structure like controller, model and views. using [Click Here](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2234/Using-MVC-With-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx)

Then I've create simple Index view in Home controller and its open successfully.(via open browser from desktop client)

Now i want to get light-Switch table data(records) in my controller via entity Framework or light-Switch data context. suggest me easiest way..

I don't know how to get data in controller using light-switch data context. so I've try with entity framework using DbContext and DbSet.

**But i got error:**

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
LightSwitchApplication.Data.[EntityName]: EntityType '[EntityName]' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
[EntityName]: EntityType: EntitySet '[EntityName]' is based on type '[EntityName]' that has no keys defined.
```

I've also got some solution for light-switch data context here [Click Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/11/19/a-new-api-for-lightswitch-server-interaction-the-serverapplicationcontext.aspx)

I've try to implement but not getting ApplicationData and CreateContext See Attached.
[image]

Your answer will appreciable

Thanks,

Jatin

Answer (score 1):

See my article: An HTML MVC LightSwitch Security Administration (http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3281/An-HTML-MVC-LightSwitch-Security-Administration.aspx) for an example.

Basically you need to have these includes:

`using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Server;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
using LightSwitchApplication.Models;`

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your answer... i've attached new image with contoller code can you please look on it again?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. the image looks the same. Did you look at the sample project I indicated? It should have what you need.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your answer.. Yes i've reviewed link that in you answer. But i didn't get any idea like how to get data in controller using light switch context or entity framework code first approach. Can you again review my scenario? Because I will not create table from visual studio. I will just connect with sql. And I will not use filter action of table. I want just my table data in controller. Can you Please suggest easiest way. Because i am beginner in light switch instead of mvc.

Comment: Hello Michael, If you want my hands-on then please tell me i will share link.

Comment: I'm sorry all I have to offer is my example. It should have what you are looking for. Unfortunately I am unable to provide personal consulting.

Comment: Okay no problem... Michael.. Can you please advice. I am stuck on that from many days.. I have one table and one list detail screen for same. data will enter from that screen and then this data i want to display in mvc view page.. please help me. :(

Comment: Try this one:http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2230/Creating-an-AngularJS-CRUD-Application-Using-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx

Comment: Hello Michael... Is it possible to connect sql db(with asp.net membership tables) instead of mdf.. into this (http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3281/An-HTML-MVC-LightSwitch-Security-Administration.aspx

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question :(

Comment: Michael.. I have sent one link in my last comment. in this example having asp.net membership tables and functionality with UI. but tables inside in mdf. How can change connection _IntrinsicData(.mdf) to External data base? I have already add data source in LS application. same tables also i am having and database. but i don't know how to change connection in LS(Light Switch). your reply will appreciable.

Comment: When you publish your LightSwitch application it puts all tables in the same sql database.